# I am trying to insert some data into status table but getting SQL Query Error in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new in Laravel. I have a table, and that table name is {**status**}.

[image]

Under the Models\ Status.php when I removed **protected $table='status';** from status.php then I am getting this error!

[image]
[image]

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view
> not found: 1146 Table 'cms.statuses' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into
> `statuses` (`status`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
> (dfg, 1, 2021-06-22 15:16:10, 2021-06-22 15:16:10))

**Here is my Table schema**

[image]

**And HomeController function**

[image]

I would be very happy if anyone can explain, why I am getting this kind of error when I'm not using this line => **protected $table='status';**
thank you!

Comment: look into this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names.you will get idea how laravel model works. Status plural form statuses

Comment: Do you have a typo error? It looks like your table is named "status" (singular), but the insert is being done to "statuses" (plural).

Comment: @JohnH I have added more 2 images, Table schema, and controller so that you can understand better, thanks!

Comment: @JohnLobo thanks for your link, I'll read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand better:

Each model is extended from `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;` So it has method called   `getTable()` like below

```
/**
  * Get the table associated with the model.
  *
  * @return string
  */
  public function getTable()
  {
     return $this->table ?? Str::snake(Str::pluralStudly(class_basename($this)));
  }
```

if you see this:

1. First it will check if you have set table property manually. If its then it will take `table name` from  `protected $table='status';`
2. Suppose if you haven't set property then it will take `class name` and then `pluralize` the name then it will convert to `snake case`.

For example in your case, `Model` name is `Status`

```
$response=Str::snake(Str::pluralStudly(class_basename("Status")));
dd($response);
```

Result will be `statuses`. So it expect `statuses` table in `database`.

For example Consider You have model name `UserDetail` then

```
$response=Str::snake(Str::pluralStudly(class_basename("UserDetail")));
dd($response);
```

then result will be `user_details`. So it expect `user_details` table in database.